# Is there any way to execute code after render is done (visually) with hooks in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a lot of data to render to table (takes several seconds to render). I need to execute some code when it is done visually. I use hooks, not classes. I tried useEffect, but it only fires when rendering starts.
Any suggestions? If I rewrite using classes with componentDidUpdate() will that help?

Comment: what do you need to execute after the DOM has been painted?

Comment: No need to rewrite your component with classes! Why does your table take several seconds to render? Are you fetching any data? It would be really helpful if you can add an example link.

Comment: Add some sample code so we can understand this problem better.

Comment: No it is not fetching.
I need to show a notification for several seconds when I manipulated data. The problem is when I have all data and I dispatch it and I am trying to show notification, react doesn’t show it for some reason while it renders the table, but when the table is rendered, notification is already hidden before it even showed. I think it might be something with React render and paint algorithms.

Comment: Here is the example code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-austin-ujzgh?file=/src/App.js

As soon as this is a simplified example, sometimes it works fine, sometimes not. On code sandbox it seems to work fine all the time, but on my local machine - it’s not.

Also the problem repeats only for the first time after reload. If you press button again after the table has already been rendered for the first time - there is no more problem (I thing because there is no need to create the whole table, only diff, which is fast).